# $\mathcal B[0,\infty) \otimes \mathcal F$-measurability of $(t,\xi) \mapsto \xi(t)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let ${\bf D} = \{\xi : [0,\infty)\to\mathbb R^d \mid \xi \text{ is right-continuous with left-limits}\}$. For each $t\ge0$, define $x_t:{\bf D}\to \mathbb R^d$ by $x_t(\xi)=\xi(t)$. We write $x_t(\xi)=x(t,\xi)$ and consider the function $x:[0,\infty)\times {\bf D}\to \mathbb R^d$.

What I want to show is that $x$ is $\mathcal B[0,\infty) \otimes \mathcal F$-measurable in $(t,\xi)$, with $\mathcal F=\sigma(x_t:t\ge 0)$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra where all $x_t$ are measurable in $\xi$.

I don't know how to prove this statement using the right-continuity (hint given). First time I tried to decompose each inverse image of compact set into product of measurable sets, but failed. What argument should I use?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x(t,\xi)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}1_{[(k-1)/n,k/n)}(t)\xi(k/n)$. (Because of right continuity.) Argue that each term in the sum is $\mathcal B[0,\infty)\otimes\mathcal F$-measurable, hence to is the sum, hence so is the limit.